# How can I safely switch Git branches while a Jupyter notebook is running on one branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, jupyter, branch

When I am running a Jupyter Notebook (under VSCode) that is constantly producing output in one Git branch, would I run into conflicts when I switch the Git branch to meanwhile work on another file/notebook?

I experienced once that my Jupyter cells kind of disappeared when I checked again, so I wonder whether this was a bug, me doing some accidental deletes or due to the branch switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a job for [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Let some job run on your repo checked out on some branch.

Add a new worktree to the repo with `git worktree add <other_dir>` and git will recreate the file structure of the repo in `<other_dir>`

Then `cd` to the new worktree and checkout any branch of the repo without interfering with whatever is running in the main worktree.

Comment: And how would I merge the two directories again?

Comment: Since your worktrees are checked out on different branches, as usual. When your process in main branch is over, commit whatever needs to be, and if the other branch is also ready to merge, merge one into the other like you would in your specific workflow. Not different than if these branches had evolved in different clones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git stash to save your work on your current branch aside and not get conflicts and change branch. Then when you come again on your first branch to get all your work from befor you can just use git stash pop.

Comment: When I stash-pop again I also see the new outputs in the Jupyter which was not there yet when I did the stashing?
And the new outputs are not mistakenly added to the branch I am in meanwhile?

Comment: No you will not see them they will be aside and you can work on the new branch safely. You only stash pop when you are back to your old branch. 
Here is the definition of git stash from the git website : 

Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

So if you stash your branch will match the HEAD commit and you can safely switch branch.

Comment: If output is *constantly* produced in the working tree, stashing at one point won't solve anything, since new files will keep on appearing and be detected by git.